# React Router 4 – organizing paths

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Since Routes in React Router 4 doesn't have a `name` property anymore, they can't be referenced when building links or when redirecting to them.

**Is there a recommended way how to handle "references"?**

What I want to say:

In all examples I saw the `path` property is defined inline.
Every time I want to build a link I have to copy & paste that string onto that link.

If I now want to change a route's path I have to find all references where I link to that Route.

For me that feels a bit odd. My idea is to create a global `routes.js` which just holds an object of a route name with the actual path as a simple key-value pair. But also this seems to be not as practical as it first sounds: Having paths with params makes it necessary to parse them accordingly.